# Matlab suptitle hidding legend

Tags: matlab, plot, legend, subplot

I am using the suptitle.m file to add a main title on a figure with 3
subplots. Each subplot has its own legend. After I issue the
suptitle command, the legend for the last plot disappears. Has anyone
else seen this before? How do I fix this?

The same question was asked 10 years ago on Matworks, with no answers.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/44980

**Extra**

If I plot the figure, and then manipulate the legends positions. And then sets the suptitle, it is the last legend that has been manipulated, which is hidden behind the plots.
This would seem like some information is hidden in memory that is used by suptitle.m

Comment: If you look in the code you can see that `suptitle()` is a helper function for a demo and that some parameters are set manually inside the code and this is probably what causes your problem. It even comes with a warning: "Warning: If the figure or axis units are non-default, this will break." The workaround given by @Naveen below should work.

Comment: @Ghaul true I read that also. I just wanted to know if others had found a solution. And as stated in the comment below, if you do as Naveen states, then the title of the subplot and the suptitle will be ontop of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
I have looked at the code and have not been able to solve the issue. But by creating suptitle before the last plot it works

```
figure()
subplot(3,1,1)
plot.....
subplot(3,1,2)
plot.....
subplot(3,1,3)
suptitle('Your Title');
plot.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the last plot after writing the `suptitle`, use it this way:

```
figure()
suptitle('Your Title');
subplot(3,1,1)
plot.....
subplot(3,1,2)
plot.....
subplot(3,1,3)
plot.....
```

This way the `suptitle` does not interfere with the legends of any of the subplots.

Comment: That is not possible, if you have a title in the first subplot they will overwrite each other and look bad

Answer (score 1):

Zhang Jiang provided a solution for the disappearing legend in suptitle as part of an x-ray toolbox. Basically, you just need to include the following line at the end of suptitle.m:

```
% fix legend if one exists
legH = legend;
if ~isempty(legH)
    axes(legH);
end
```

This will re-activate the missing legend.

Follow Jiang's implementation of [suptitle.m](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6026-toolbox--x-ray-refraction-of-matter/content/xrayrefraction/suptitle.m). Search the script for "legend" to find the piece of code with the solution.

Sauro Salomoni